# Ubuntu doesn't find hdds with higher clock rates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, overclocking

I dual boot windows 7 64-bit and ubuntu 13.10 64-bit on separate disks, and utilize some overclocking from the BIOS. Windows works fine, however ubuntu can't seem to find any hard drives, except for at stock cpu speeds. While attempting to boot it says `Gave up waiting for root device...` and `ALERT! /dev/sdb7 does not exist. Dropping to shell!` A bootable usb stick still works, but gparted doesn't detect any other drives.

Have tried:

- Boot-repair
- Changing SATA mode in BIOS
- Newer kernels
- Older ubuntu versions

Not sure it's relevant, but the motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-A75M-UD2H with the newest BIOS version, the CPU an AMD Llano.

This is hardly a fatal error, but it's inconvenient to change BIOS settings whenever I want to switch OS, and furthermore I'm quite curious about why it won't work. I'd appreciate any insight into what the actual problem is.

So how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: You mean you can boot from the USB into a live session and you _still_ don't see any HDDs? Weird. Does `sudo fdisk -l` show anything?

Comment: By overclocking this particular system you have made the hardware act differently in some way. There are many possible reasons why this could happen (timing glitches, slightly different SATA/RAM protocols or timing implementations etc.) and it is likely impossible to diagnose exactly why without detailed analysis in a hardware lab. If you value your data you should not run an overclocked system where this has been shown to affect behaviour of the drive (that also applies to Windows - perhaps it does not always work and will eventually / silently corrupt the drive).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the Raid config on your drive, if not just boot to a live cd/usb, enter terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

also try

```
sudo dmraid -rE
```

worked for me